# использование spl_autoload_register

Tags: php

День добрый, подскажите в чем преимущество использования spl_autoload_register,  к примеру я написал не большой класс который ,как я думаю, делает тоже самое - класс сканирует  указанные директории ( к примеру /core/,/plugins/) и через цикл подключает все необходимые классы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С spl_autoload_register() ваш код будет совместим со всеми остальными PHP-библиотеками, например, которые загружаются через Composer. Более того, стандарт PSR-4 прямо требует использования spl_autoload_register(). Это, конечно, не вот что металлическое требование, но года через 2-3, а местами уже и сейчас, ваш код будет восприниматься PHP-сообществом как некорректно оформленный.